# I want to understand why the app gives me static file response without including UseStaticFile() middleware in the middleware pipeline?

Tags: c#, css, asp.net-core-mvc

I don't include UseStaticFile middleware but I can get a response when I request for a static file. Can someone explain why this is the case?

There is a CSS folder in the `wwwroot` and `site.css` file in the CSS folder

I am making the following request `https://localhost:7284/css/site.css`

It is not supposed to return a response because I did not include UseStaticFile(), but it gives me the CSS file that is requested

Here is the code:

```
using PathenyShop.Models;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Server;   

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddScoped<IPieRepository,PieRepository>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<ICategoryRepository,CategoryRepository>();

builder.Services.AddScoped<IShopingCart, ShopingCart>(sp => ShopingCart.GetCart(sp));
builder.Services.AddSession(); 

builder.Services.AddHttpContextAccessor();



builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews(); 
builder.Services.AddDbContext<BethanyPieShopDbContext>(options =>
{
    options.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("BethanyPieShopDbContextConnection"));
});


var app = builder.Build();


app.UseSession();

if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
   var s=app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
}


app.MapDefaultControllerRoute(); // "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{Id?}"
DbInitializer.Seed(app);

app.Run();
```

Expected Result:

- No response to the request because there is no static file middleware!

Steps that I have tried:

- Please mention here the things that you have tried to solve this issue.
- Try 2

Comment: What static file are you able to access? Please [edit] your question to add debugging steps.

Answer (score 0):

`WebApplication.CreateBuilder` will internally call `ConfigureWebHostDefaults` which in turn will

> configure WebRootFileProvider to include static web assets from projects referenced by the entry assembly during development

As per the documentation here:

- [GenericHostBuilderExtensions.ConfigureWebHostDefaults Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.hosting.generichostbuilderextensions.configurewebhostdefaults?view=aspnetcore-7.0)

Additionally, this seems to only be setup when running in "development" mode. Can you double check if you can still access those files when running in "production" mode? (you can easily change the mode in the launchSettings.json file in your project under "Properties").

If you want more control over what is included, you can configure it all manually, or you can also look into [the new `CreateBuilderSlim` method coming up in .NET 8](https://github.com/dotnet/AspNetCore.Docs/blob/main/aspnetcore/release-notes/aspnetcore-8.0.md#new-createslimbuilder-method).